# JavaScript Array with Multiple Strings for Passing Querystring to SSRS Report

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

I have an application where I am trying to make the URL querystring pass to an SSRS report.

If I just list one string, the querystring accepts the string, however, when listing to multiple strings, the querystring does not accept the strings in the JavaScript into the parameters of the report. I am showing my JavaScript code below.

I would like to receive help structuring this JavaScript so that I could list multiple strings and have the string fill the querystring and hence the SSRS Report.

```html
function launchSsrsReport()
    {
        var AssignedTo = $('#linkAssignedTo').text();
        AssignedTo = AssignedTo.trim();
        var StartDateString = $('#pcDateImported').text();
        StartDateString = StartDateString.trim();

        var StartDate = new Date(StartDateString);

        var startDateUrl = StartDate.getMonth()+1  + "/" + StartDate.getDate() + "/" + StartDate.getFullYear();
        var EndDate = new Date();
        var endDateUrl = EndDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + EndDate.getDate() + "/" + EndDate.getFullYear();

        //need to pass in a Status from the application
        var Status = "Pending"; //for testing only
        //var Status = ["Pending, In Process"];
        
        var qs = getJsonFromUrl();
        var url = "https://urlofwebserver/ReportServer_SQL?/ParentFolder/Subfolder/ReportFolder/Report&StartDate=" + startDateUrl + "&EndDate=" + endDateUrl + "&AssignedTo=" + AssignedTo + "&Status=" + Status + "&SubmissionIds=" + qs["id"];
        window.location.href = url;
    }

    function getJsonFromUrl() {
        var query = location.search.substr(1);
        var result = {};
        query.split("&").forEach(function (part) {
            var item = part.split("=");
            result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by the report "not accepting" the values? Do you get an error or a blank report? How are you separating the concatenated values once they get to the report?

Comment: The parameters get passed onto the querystring but the parameters do not fill the combo box. The way its all done is in that javascript. What makes this var different is that there are a total of 23 strings and in many cases they are more than one word strings.

Comment: You are going to have lots of trouble with this approach because the URL string has to be encoded (no spaces or other special characters). There is also a relatively low character limit. Also you can't just set the default parameter value through the URL. The URL will contain one delimited string that you have to split into an array of values using an expression in the report. Consider passing a list of IDs instead then translate those in the report if possible.